# MySQL : How to order by two or more columns and the NULL's value will be last?

Tags: php, mysql, coalesce

Trying to order the column name is not null as first, if the first column is null but not second column is not null etc..

Table :

```
id  name1 name2  name3
1.   a     b      
2.   a1            c
3.         b1      c1
4.                 c2
5.                 c3
6.   a2    
7.         b2      c4
8.   a3
```

Expected result

```
id 
1 
2
6
8
3
7
4
5
```

I have tried to use COALESCE  AND IFNULL But it's return zero result.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle).

Comment: `ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(my_field),1,0),my_field;`

Comment: This schema could probably benefit from normalisation.

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [`COALESCE(value,...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

> Returns the first non-`NULL` value in the list, or `NULL` if there are no non-`NULL` values.
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
>         -> NULL
> ```

As documented under [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null):

> Tests whether a value is `NULL`.
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 0 IS NULL, NULL IS NULL;
>         -> 0, 0, 1
> ```

Therefore:

```sql
SELECT   id
FROM     Table1
ORDER BY COALESCE(name1, name2, name3) IS NULL,
         COALESCE(name1, name2, name3)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdadf/1/0).

This sorts first on whether all three columns are `NULL` (those that *are* will have an `IS NULL` result of one, which will come after those that *aren't* with a result of zero); then by the actual value of the first non-`NULL` column.

Comment: When i try this in active record the query showing error :
$this->db->order_by("COALESCE(name1,name2) IS NULL");

Comment: @AaruKarthiga: Am I supposed to guess what error is shown, or are you going to tell me?